# Hook key & key combinations from keyboard with Qt 4.6

Tags: qt4, keyboard, events, hook, qt4.6

Let's say I have a window-less application which has only an icon on the Taskbar (Windows, Mac OS X & Linux). I want it to capture some key & key combinations, let's say Right Control + Right Shift. Upon keying in correct, combination, it will do something, say take screenshot. I can do window-less app, icon on the Taskbar and screen capture but I don't know how to monitor keyboard globally for key combinations. Please kindly advise. Any help or hint is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To my mind, you couldn't grab or capture key, since you don't have the focus onto your window.

Comment: Just curious. Are you waiting for more thorough answer than mine? ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global shortcuts in a cross-platform application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813823/global-shortcuts-in-a-cross-platform-application)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System-wide key grabbing is a tricky subject, but system-wide key hooking is even trickier. Every OS/GUI has its own solution, at least for grabbing. Qt4 doesn't expose such feature, but [Qt eXTension library](http://www.libqxt.org/) solves the problem with its [QxtGlobalShortcut](http://doc.libqxt.org/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html). It's a nice wrapper for:

- [XGrabKey()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html)/[XUngrabKey()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XUngrabKey.html) in X11,
- [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx)/[UnregisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646327(VS.85).aspx) in Windows,
- RegisterEventHotKey()/UnregisterEventHotKey() in Mac OS X.

So you can grab explicit key combination, i.e. particular key and modifiers (XGrabKey() allows a bit more), that no other application will get. Key sequences, i.e. consecutive key combinations, are not supported here.

---

Keyboard hooking is much more powerful, because it allows peeking at the input events (or even filtering them). It's not only used by keyboard loggers, but they are a typical association here.

If you're into Windows, then you can read:

- [Hooks and DLLs](http://www.flounder.com/hooks.htm) by Joseph M. Newcomer,
- [Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589.aspx).

In X11 it's much more complicated. There are at least a two pages you may want to read:

- [X.Org Wiki - Development/Documentation/InputEventProcessing](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/InputEventProcessing) - to have some background,
- [Exploiting X11 to monitor keystrokes](http://www.capo-nord.org/soci/xmav/articolo.php?id=20080417) - to understand difficulties.

There was a [X Event Interception Extension](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XEvIE), but it wasn't maintained and eventually has been removed.

Hopefully it can be done without the help of X11 infrastructure. In Linux 2.6 kernel there is "Event interface", known as [evdev](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/input/input.txt), that can be exploited here. Details can be found in the source code of the [logkeys Linux keylogger](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/). It can also be done with something in effect similar to evdev. See my PoC project:
[kaos](http://github.com/przemoc/kaos) - Key Activity On-Screen display.

And I don't have Mac, so no further references. ;)

Comment: +1 thanks. I didn't notice your answer. I'm using libqxt with no success in Mac OS X.

Comment: As I said, I am not a Mac user, so I cannot help you here. Sorry.

Comment: Interesting, [Win32 Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) is now an empty page with `Content Removed`. Is it my fault? ;) I'll update above answer. Don't worry, there is a [Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/).
`http://web.archive.org/web/20080510093117/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx)` - Win32 Hooks by Kyle Marsh