# Qt: receive keyboard events when my application doesn't have focus

Tags: qt

I am writing a Qt application. At the first stage I want to receive all key press events, system-wide, **without creating any widgets**.

Is this possible in Qt, or do I have to hook into the underlying window system? (This needs to be cross-platform.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The keypresses control behaviour in a non-gui component. At the moment I have a dummy window for capturing focus, but that prevents me from doing other things. Also, my X11 setup is focus-follows-mouse, so I can't click on anything either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980141/hook-key-key-combinations-from-keyboard-with-qt-4-6 seems to fit.

Comment: Has anything changed in the last 4 years that makes this easier?