# Qt: How receive keyboard events when my application doesn't have focus in Qt5 specifically?

Tags: qt, qt5, hook, keyhook

I have the exact same problem of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788332/qt-receive-keyboard-events-when-my-application-doesnt-have-focus): I want to make a software which, once executed, will monitor for a specific key event (press of F12) and will do something (do repeated mouse clicks: an auto clicker). But I'ld like, if possible, to use Qt himself to do the trick instead of calling Windows's functions (especially because it may well be eventually used in Linux, so a cross-platform solution is desired)

Well my problem isn't anything new including for Qt users as the link above shows. Moreover, a decent answer was already posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980141/hook-key-key-combinations-from-keyboard-with-qt-4-6), but it involves the use of `Qt eXTension` in a Qt 4 context, and that is outdated. In fact, it's so outdated that when I tried to access the eXTension link, my Chrome browser warned me of being an insecure website! So what I would like to know specifically is **if there is any Qt 5, specifically, solution to this problem**, given that eXTension is out of question, or if I'll have to do a OS key hook after all. A Qt5 free library will also be acceptable.

Comment: No, Qt only handles the events when it has focus so you will have to use the library of each OS unfortunately.

Comment: Forked from qxt (Qt eXTension), just in case you don't find anything else: https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut

Comment: Another Github project for you: [QHotkey](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey).