# Create QAction with shortcut, without inserting in menu

Tags: c++, qt, bind, qaction

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <cassert>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QAction* back = new QAction(this);
    back->setVisible(true);
    back->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+M"));
    bool cres = connect(back, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
    assert(cres);
}
```

In this code I tried to catch `Ctrl+M` key event. I don't want to put the action in menu. `connect` returns true but `mySlot` is never called. When action is inserted in menu, shortcut works well. What I have done wrong?

Comment: If you want to use "headless" (without GUI) shortcuts, I would recommend using `QShortcut` class directly.

Comment: @vahancho: `QShortcut` doesn't do anything without the gui. Quoth documentation: "A shortcut is "listened for" by Qt's event loop when the shortcut's parent widget is receiving events."

Comment: @KubaOber, yes, but what I meant was that QShortcut doesn't have a visual representation, as QAction may have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QAction` is dormant until you insert it somewhere.  As vahancho has suggested, use `QShortcut`. You need to instantiate the shortcut for each top-level widget (window) where you want it to be active. Thus if you have 5 top-level windows, you'll need 5 shortcuts, each having one of windows as its parent.

There is no way to use `QShortcut` as a global shortcut without the gui. `QShortcut` is only active when its associated widget has focus. The widget could be a top-level window.

System-global shortcuts are the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813823/global-shortcuts-in-a-cross-platform-application).).