# RegisterHotKey confusion

Tags: c++, qt, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I want to set a "global" hotkey for my program. More specifically, I want to set a key sequence (CTRL + q, CTRL + t, etc) that will do something (close program, start timer, etc) without the need for my program to be focused. I know how to set a shortcut using QShortcut, but obviously it only works when the program is being focused.

I've read that it's possible using RegisterHotKey, but I don't understand how it works. For one reason or another, it's a confusing concept for me to grasp because I haven't found anything that explains it very well. Do I need a while loop in order to work? Can someone explain how to do this or maybe give a good example I could mess around with?

Answer (score 0):

I put together a pretty thorough answer a while back.  This should get you up and running pretty quickly.

[Clipboard Shortcut/Hotkey binding with Qt outside of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504995/clipboard-shortcut-hotkey-binding-with-qt-outside-of-application/18521207#18521207)

Hope that helps.