# How to run a QT application in background mode?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5.5

I created an application that moves the mouse cursor using keys on keyboard, but when I minimize the window it doesn't work anymore.

How to do it so that it works even if the app is minimized and even if I go to another virtual desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate (Qt4): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980141/hook-key-key-combinations-from-keyboard-with-qt-4-6

Comment: What you are trying to do is called 'Hooking'. If this is Windows you could use SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: Thanks! You helped me :)